# I have a visualforce page where i am displaying map of accounts using apex:PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page where i am displaying map of accounts using apex:PageBlockTable. But i am getting the error saying "Map key null not found in map
Error is in expression '{!mapOfAccountAndRecords[indexvalue]}' in component apex:pageBlockTable in page showaccounts". Can any one explain where i am doing wrong?

```
<apex:page controller="ShowAccountsController">
<apex:pageBlock title="Accounts"> 
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapOfKeys}" var="indexvalue" >
        <apex:repeat value="{!mapOfAccountAndRecords[indexvalue]}" var="acc">
            <apex:column style="width: 300px">
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

</apex:page>

**Controller:**

```
public class ShowAccountsController {
Public Map<Integer,List<Account>> mapOfAccountAndRecords  {get;set;}
Public Integer Counter;
public List<Integer> mapOfKeys  {get;set;}
public ShowAccountsController(){
    Counter = 0;
    mapOfKeys = new List<Integer>();
    mapOfAccountAndRecords = new Map<Integer,List<Account>>();
    retrieveAccountRecords(); 
    for(Integer i:mapOfAccountAndRecords.keySet()){
        mapOfKeys.add(i);
    }
    system.debug('mapOfAccountAndRecords is '+mapOfAccountAndRecords);
}
public void retrieveAccountRecords(){
    List<Account> listOfAccountRecords = [select id,name from account];
    for(Account acc:listOfAccountRecords){
        Counter = Counter+1;
        List<Account> accRecordList = new List<Account>();
        accRecordList.add(acc);
        mapOfAccountAndRecords.put(Counter,accRecordList);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The map that you are iterating has the counter as the key and the value is a list of Accounts. As the Value part of the map is a List you need to iterate over that list and get each node's value.

The map response is like below-

```
{
  1=(Account:{Id=0010200000FMXXXXXX, Name=Roberts, RecordTypeId=0125f0000009ZY9AAM}),
  2=(Account:{Id=0010200000FMhXXXXX, Name=Avent, RecordTypeId=0125f0000009ZY9AAM})
}
```

If your ask is just to show a list of accounts then I think your approach isn't proper as it can be taken care of by iterating the List Simply.

However, I suggest the below code modification to your code to fetch the Account Id and Account Name in 2 columns.

```
<apex:page controller="ShowAccountsController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapOfKeys}" var="indexvalue" >
            <apex:column style="width: 300px">
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Id</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!mapOfAccountAndRecords[indexvalue]}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column style="width: 300px">
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:repeat  value="{!mapOfAccountAndRecords[indexvalue]}" var="mapVar">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!mapVar.Name}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far too complicated for your objective - no map is required

```
public class ShowAccountsController {
 public Account[] getAccounts() {
   return [SELECT Id, Name, .. FROM Account];
 }
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="ShowAccountsController">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts"> 
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc" >
      
        <apex:column style="width: 300px">
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}" />
  
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```